# How do I theme the user profile?

Tags: 8, theming

I would like to create a custom template for the user profile view. With the help of "Theme debug" I figured out that I need to create a template named html--user.html.twig, but even if I copy all content of page.html.twig to my new template, I do get a blank page for any user profile now. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I cleared all caches though.

Which content do I have to copy to a custom template (suggested file name)?

Answer (score 4):

html--user.html.twig would be the template file used instead of [html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21html.html.twig/8) when viewing a user profile (for example, for http://example.com/user/1). It is not the template file that shows the content of a user profile, but it's the template file that contains the basic structure of a Drupal page; in fact, its default content is the following one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
    <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </head>
  <body{{ attributes }}>
    <a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable">
      {{ 'Skip to main content'|t }}
    </a>
    {{ page_top }}
    {{ page }}
    {{ page_bottom }}
    <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

[page.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21page.html.twig/8) is the template file for a generic page; that is why you are getting a white page for user profile pages.

The template file for a user profile is [user.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21templates%21user.html.twig/8), and its default content is the following one.

```
<article{{ attributes }}>
  {% if content %}
    {{- content -}}
  {% endif %}
</article>
```

As you see the variable it receives are completely different from the ones the other two template files (html.html.twig and page.html.twig) receive. That is why using the wrong template gives you a blank page.